# Jquery cannot read custom tag text on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, custom-tags

I would like to use custom tag into my html page and use jquery to read the text in it,
something like :

```
<desc>Hello world</desc>
```

then with jquery I read the text with :

```
desc_text=$("desc").first().text();
```

On firefox and Chrome, it works, I got the 'Hello world', but not with Internet Explorer (IE 9).

After debugging, it seems that the problem comes from IE : `<desc>` and `</desc>` are seen as two different DOM nodes. The `Hello world` is not a child node of `<desc>`.
That's the reason it does not work. If I use the `span` tag instead of the `desc` tag : it works.

Is there a way to make it works on IE, or is that normal that IE does not interpret my custom tag like firefox / Chrome ?

Comment: Why would you want custom tags in the first place? Just use proper IDs and Classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add on the head of your document

```
<script>document.createElement('desc');</script>
```

this is the basic idea also adopted from `HTML5shiv` to make IE<9 able to properly parse the new HTML5 elements (anyway be aware that you won't be able to inject dinamycally this element via javascript into the DOM)

Answer (score 1):

http://ajaxian.com/archives/adding-custom-tags-to-internet-explorer-the-official-way