# Jquery selecting innerText of custom tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, innertext

I'm hoping this is fairl simple but having done a lot of googling and experimenting with selectors, find(), content(), text(), etc I'm not quite getting this right. Any help would be appreciated.

I have some custom markup in the web page.

```
<div id="myGrid">
    <url>www.google.com</url>
    <columns>
        <column>ID</column>
        <column>Position</column>
        <column>FirstName</column>
        <column>LastName</column>
    </columns>
</div>
```

I need to select the text of `<url>` into a variable.
I also need to get a collection of `<columns>`'s into a variable (array/collection).

The tag name will be the identifier, i.e. I can't use an ID or CLASS to find these elements.

Seems like it should be do-able but my attempts so far are hit and miss... any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery cannot read custom tag text on Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313110/jquery-cannot-read-custom-tag-text-on-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $t = {}
var i = 0;   

$('#myGrid').find('column').each(function(){

    $t[i] = $(this).text();
    i++;

});

alert($('#myGrid url').text());
alert($t.toSource());
```

Comment: Thanks, the first alert works just fine but the 2nd is not executing. for me unfortunately.

Comment: @user1389920 try to change: `$t[i]` with `$t['N'+i]` and alert($t.N0) or alert($t.N1)

Comment: Update: Ah! .toSource() was throwing an exception when I debugged. (Using Jquery 1.7.2?). Tried iterating over the array with $.each() and it works great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I will give you help with the url because it is very basic.  This should help you out with the columns.

Jquery will select any element you give.  You are able to use any element name.  Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cNwv/) here.

IF you are worried about IE issues, use `document.createElement('url')` which will tell IE that url is an element of the document

```
document.createElement('url');  //crutch for IE

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('url').html());  
})​
```

Comment: Thanks got it, the createElement() function I will keep in mind, didn't think of this before.

Comment: Many thanks, document.createElment() is a key here. I have a further question though. Including this code in the head of my document works perfeclty. However, I need to extract it to a .JS file. I've added this line of code to the $(document).ready(); function but this causes it to fail, could you advise on this? I'm guessing the loading order is incorrect somehow.

Comment: @user1389920 do not add `document.createElement()` within the document ready call.  This needs to be written before the url element is used in the page

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = $("url").html();
var columns = $.makeArray($("column").find("columns").html());
```

Although I haven't tested the above, a better way would be to use the jQuery 'each' function:

```
var a = Array();
$('#myGrid').find('column').each(function(){
    a.push($(this).html());
});
```

And to test: `alert(a[2]);` where the number is the array number.

Where url is your url (duh) and columns is your column array.  This would work great if there's only one or if you're using this within a function, in which case I would change the selectors to `$("url", this).html();`

Answer (score 0):

How about this (jsbin version http://jsbin.com/ucivav)?

```
var url = $("#myGrid url").text();
var $cols = $("#myGrid columns column");
alert(url);
alert($cols.first().text());
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great to get url. I thought I had tried this so no idea what I had done wrong before. For cols... the alert is empty string.

Comment: I think I might have given you the wrong version of the jsbin file - try http://jsbin.com/ucivav/5